# OpenCV on Android focus on upper part

Tags: android, android-camera, setfocus

I am using Open CV on Android studio. How can I focus on the upper part on the frame? I am using `CameraBridgeViewBase`. I tried to set `cameraBridgeViewBase.setFocusable(true);` and
`cameraBridgeViewBase.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`. Both does not work when I click to focus. I saw some said use `parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);`, but `Camera Parameter` class is deprecated.

Thank you.